# Работа в django с  MySQL

Tags: mysql, django

В settings.py прописано:

```
DATABASES = {
    "default": {

        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'name',
        'USER': 'user',
        'PASSWORD': 'password',
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}
```

При запуске сервера (python manage.py runserver) появляется ошибка:

> raise ImproperlyConfigured("Error
> loading MySQLdb module: %s" % e)
> django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured:
> Error loading MySQLdb module: No
> module named MySQLdb

Использую Ubuntu 14/64bit
Перед этим установил python-mysqldb

sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb

Читал на форумах, что проблема через 64-битную систему?

Как устранить ошибку?

Comment: У меня 64-битная ubuntu, и импорт отрабатывает нормально. Возможно, вы поставили модуль для одной версии Питона, а проект запускаете с другой? Попробуйте вне проекта запустить в консоли Python и проверить, что происходит при `import MySQLdb`.

Answer (score 1):

mysql-python он же python-mysqldb работает только на Python от 2.4 до 2.7 версии, убедитесь, что у Вас правильная версия питона.

Comment: Использую Python2.7

Comment: Попробуйте сделать, как сказал @Arcady Chumachenko, запустить интерактивный интерпритатор python и выполнить import mysqldb.